# Tableau Pie-Chart with Measures

Tags: pie-chart, tableau-api

I have data with many measures values for each SiteID, i.e.

```
Total Windows    Total Mac    Total Online    Total Offline    Total Computers    SiteID
```

I have been googling how to create pie chart in Tableau, but these tutorials assume I have data that looks like

```
 OS    Status    SiteID
```

What I am ultimately trying to do is create a pie chart of online vs offline users and use actions from other data points to filter that chart.

I just need to know how to create pie-chart and from there I can create action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you want to make a pie chart showing online users vs. offline users, and be able to filter it by SiteID.

You could do this by:

1. Go to Marks and select Pie.
2. Drag `[Measure Names]` into Color.
3. Drag `[Measure Values]` into Angle.
4. Remove all pills except for `[Total Online]` and `[Total Offline]` from the Measure Values card.

Then you can create a SiteID filter by creating a quick filter, dragging SiteID to the filter card, or using an action from a dashboard.

Comment: Might I suggest a donut chart to make it more appealing/readable? https://www.interworks.com/blog/tmccullough/2014/03/06/tableau-cookbook-donut-charts

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to reshape your data. Can you use SQL to do so?

Comment: How do you mean shape data? Please give example. If this is my last last last resort, then I have no choice :-(